# Ext JS localization with Sencha CMD application

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to implement localization with Ext JS 6.2.0. The application is generated by Sencha Cmd. I'm following the Ext JS [localization documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/guides/core_concepts/localization.html) and [Saki's blog post](http://extjs.eu/localization-of-ext-applications/).

This is what I've done:

First, I've created a simple panel.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.MyPanel',{
    xtype: 'mypanel',
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    title: 'Hello World',
});
```

Then, I created a 'locale' directory under the 'app' directory, and created an 'es' directory under 'locale'

Next, I created an override class inside the 'app/locale/es'

```
Ext.define('MyApp.locale.es.MyPanel',{
    override: 'MyApp.view.main.MyPanel',
    title:'Hola Mundo'
});
```

Finally, I modified the 'app.json'. 
I've edited 'requires' and 'overrride' sections and added 'locale' setting

```
"locale": "es",

"overrides": [
    "overrides",
    "app/locale/${app.locale}"
],

"requires": [
    "font-awesome",
    "ext-locale"
],
```

After I run 'Sencha app build', I can see the Ext JS components (e.g. button text, date picker) have been changed to Spanish, but the title of 'mypanel' is still 'Hello World'.

Comment: Try wrapping the title in a config block in the override.

Comment: Thanks @EvanTrimboli. It works!

Comment: It works now. But I want to dynamically change locale, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508992/ext-js-dynamically-change-locale-settings-of-app-json) .